# Auto enter items into 3rd party website

Tags: windows, file, firefox, batch-file, command

So I have to scan and manually enter 1200 scanner number every week for inventory. The process goes in this order:

Open Website < Click text box < Enter numbers < hit submit < wait 20 seconds < hit submit again (it makes me confirm i entered right) < Wait another 20 seconds.

At this point, the page refreshes, and IO start over at the Click text box part.

I already converted the numbers to barcodes and scan them instead of typing, I also use 2 screens with 8 open windows to make it a bit faster.

But I was wondering if there was a batch file or another way to automate the process?

Even with the scanner, and 8 open windows, it takes 4 hours roughly to do them all.

I have been searching on google for a few days, and decided to ask here since most the pages i read go back to this site.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.autohotkey.com/
Awesome macro software. Very flexible for a macro and easy language to learn.

Comment: I'm checking this out now!

Comment: Let me know if you like it! I use it for any repetitive tasks i can think of. Even works for game automation in a lot of cases haha

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for automated keyboard/mouse macro software. Never used it, just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be similar on SuperUser: [Redirecting input from file to command-line program](https://superuser.com/questions/366651/redirecting-input-from-file-to-command-line-program/366671#comment1096050_366671)

It appears to be effective for telnet sessions - not sure about http sessions. You might look into TCL and Expect as options though.